# Copy external linked file to a root of a web site

Tags: visual-studio-2012, msbuild

In Visual Studio 2012

I have three web sites that all use the same set of database connection strings.

I keep database connections strings in a `connectionStrings.config` file which is in a common solution folder (external to all three web sites).

I included this file as a link (configured as `Content` and `Copy Always`) - which copies `connectionString.config` file to each web site's `bin` folder when I compile/run web site.

I would like to copy that file to the root of each web site instead. Is there an easy way to accomplish that?

One way to do this is to use `xcopy` in post-build step of the project.

The other solution would be to modify `.csproj` file (or a separate, external `.target` file) to copy linked file to the root (instead of to `$(OutputDir)`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used a Post-Build event.  It has macro's for the place you want the file to end up.

Just use the $(Macro) tags with a few "..", and you can "massage" the files to where you want them.

```
copy $(ProjectDir)..\connectionStrings.config $(TargetDir)connectionStrings.config
```